# Do state-channels only work for transactions that affect the sender negatively?

Tags: transactions, state-channels

Mind the payment-channel case:

- Parties `A` and `B` lock the state of their balances, `S0`, on the blockchain.
- `A` makes a transaction by updating the state to `S1`, signing it and sending to `B`.
- `B` makes a transaction by updating the state to `S2`, signing it and sending to `A`.

That can go on and on indefinitely. Now, suppose, instead of payment-channel, we're trying to implement a chess game off-chain. They bet $50 on the outcome.

- Players `A`, `B` init a new game on the blockchain and lock the board state, `S`.
- Player `A` performs a move by updating the board state to `S1`, signing it, sending to `B`.
- Player `B` checks `A`'s move was valid, performs a transaction the same way.

That, again, goes on for a while. As soon, though, as `A` performs a move that is clearly advantageous to him - say, capturing `B`'s queen - `B` will just not sign anything on top of `A`'s move, forcing him to continue on the blockchain.

Does that mean that state-channels only work for transactions that affect the sender negatively?

Comment: Of course there are cases when `B` will stop playing fairly, but what benefit does he get from this? He'll lose his money either way

Answer (score 2):

In general any situation where one side has nothing to lose by misbehaving can be fixed by making them put up a bond against misbehviour, provided that misbehaviour is detectable and can be proved to the smart contract. That would work in your example.

The need for a bond may reduce the attractiveness of playing, however.